# Sculpt breaking when remeshing and using brushes

Tags: sculpting, remesh

While sculpting, I came across a problem in blender. After sculpting for a while and having remeshed my models multiple times without any problems, after remeshing my model once again, my model started to break when I used any brush on it.

I have tried adding another shape into my scene and remeshing it, and everything in my scene seems to have the same issue.
I tried going back to an earlier version of my work, but the problem is still there, even if it wasn't there when I made the save.
I tried opening the file in another version of blender, but it simply crashes on startup.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Edit: When I make a new file and append the objects that had problems from the old file, it works again like normal.

[image: Before, when I was having no problems at all]

[image: After remeshing when I use any brush on the object]

Edit: This is what happens when I add a UV sphere, remesh it and sculpt on it.
[image]

Comment: If you want to have just one mesh, you need to join the individual objects (body+legs+tail) and then remesh them. Otherwise, there will be separate objects, each with its own mesh. Select them in *Object* mode and press+J to join the objects.

Comment: @Blunder I never tried to join the objects nor do I want to, this is not related to the problem